# twitter bootstrap screen size logic and best practices

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am building responsive site using Bootstrap 3.

***Here is the desktop version(only header included):***

[image: header desktop]

***Here is the mobile version:***

[image: header mobile]

What is the concept for achieving layout change like this using Bootstrap 3, is it in usage of grid classes or media queries?

I would really appreciate short example.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the responsive utility 'hidden-lg' (hides on desktop) and 'hidden-sm' (hides on tablets/phones) CSS classes like this..

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse hidden-sm">
      <div class="container">
        .. menu here
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hidden-lg text-center">
  <!--custom select menu here-->
  <select><option>Contact Us</option><option>About</option><option>Link</option</select>
</div>
```

**Demo: http://www.bootply.com/70810**

But, the more typical Bootstrap "thing to do" is use the `nav-collapse` to collapse the menu on smaller devices:

http://www.bootply.com/cskelly/70636